# How to check in Python if file is fully downloaded after click action on selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple script here where I would use selenium to use google chrome to visit a website, click on a button(cannot use wget as there is no url). The click action starts a download. The script should close the chromedriver only when the file is fully downloaded ( when the .crdownload temp file does not exist)

I am not sure how best to implement a check though. How can I check in Python if file is fully downloaded?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import glob
import os, os.path
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


#did not use options for this sample script
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/webdriver/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'C:\Users\external\gen_dir'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)

print('download paramaters executed')


#Get a file and download it, good website for download testing
driver.get("https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download")

# initialize an object to the location on the html page and click on it to download a scrambled 10 mb file

#Looks for the 10 mb button
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main-col > div > div > div:nth-child(8) > p:nth-child(1) > a > img')
#click action
search_input.click()

#NEED TO IMPLEMENT SOME SORT OF CHECK HERE AS DRIVER CLOSES BEFORE FILE IS DOWNLOADED

driver.quit()
print('driver closed')
```

I thought of using glob to continually check for the existence of the chrome download temp file (extension ".crdownload") every 5 seconds or so, but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

```
DIR = r'C:\Users\external\gen_dir'

def wait_download(path_to_downloads):

    #Counts how many files have that extension, if there is one it returns true
    dlCounter = len(glob.glob1(path_to_downloads,"*.crdownload"))
    if dlCounter == 1:
        dl_wait = True
    else:
        dl_wait = False
    return dl_wait
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.